# How to load an image with libavcodec functions of ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

How can we open and load a BMP or PNG or JPEG file using the functions in the libavcodec of ffmpeg? I use gcc.

Thanks!

Comment: See `doc/examples/demuxing_decoding.c` and other examples.

Comment: Thanks LordNeckBeard. I checked this demuxing_decoding.c but didn't find any relevant function. Could you please tell me which function I should use?